# How can I set a margin equal to "five spaces"?

Tags: formatting

How can one set a margin equal to five spaces? Especially for a quote.

Answer (score 12):

LaTeX uses `\leftmargini` for the left margin of many of its list environments including `quote`. The latter uses the same amount for the right margin.
The margin can be set via `\settowidth`:

```
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\ \ \ \ \ }
```

Because TeX merges consecutive spaces, I have used
the command `\`  that sets a normal inter word space.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\ \ \ \ \ }% five spaces

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{quote}
    \lipsum[4]
  \end{quote}
  \lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `quoting` package, together with `calc`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{quoting,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{quoting}[indentfirst=false,leftmargin=\widthof{\ \ \ \ \ }]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{quoting}
\makebox[\widthof{\ \ \ \ \ }]{\hrulefill}\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

The `\makebox` is just to show that the margin is set to what you wanted.

[image]

Of course, you'd want to define an environment for this:

```
\newenvironment{zjquoting}[1][]
  {\begin{quoting}[indentfirst=false,leftmargin=\widthof{\ \ \ \ \ },#1]}
  {\end{quoting}}
```

The purpose of the optional argument is to allow adding other options in particular cases, for instance

```
\begin{zjquoting}[font=itshape]
```

would typeset the quotation in italics.